# How to create submenu drop down delay

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a horizontal menu that looks something like this:

```
                    Home    Shop    Sale    B2B    About    Contact
```

When you hover over any of these parents links there are child links associated with them.

Like this:

```
                    Home    SHOP    Sale    B2B    About    Contact
            Shop 1    Shop 2    Shop 3    Shop 4
```

My issue is that when I am navigating through my links and my mouse movements are not spot on, it becomes very difficult to maneuver around my menu without straying over onto the parent links and displaying a different set of child menu items.

So what I would like to achieve is the follow:

If my 'SHOP' parent menu was open and displaying 'Shop 1 - Shop 4' and I were to briefly stray over the 'Sale' parent menu link, the child links for 'Sale' would not appear unless I hovered over 'Sale' for a couple of seconds.

How can I achieve this with CSS & HTML only? My menu is quite complex so I have been trying to figure it out playing around on this menu:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fphffq2b/)

Comment: try using css transitions and set your preferred delay time, check answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try using css transitions on hover of your elements like

```
#item:hover{
     /*your styles here*/
     -moz-transition:all 1s linear;
     -webkit-transition:all 1s linear;
     -o-transition:all 1s linear;
     transition:all 1s linear;
}
```

In my case, I have used `1s` as the delay time. You can change it to any value you like.